# window.scrollTo() doesn't work with overflow and 100vh height

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Let say that I have an HTML setup like this and I want to make a `scrollTo` button, as I read that the scrollTo doesn't work with `height: 100vh` and `overflow: auto`

How should I work around this issue?

**NOTE**: TBH I work on Reactjs, and my `JSX` file more or less looks like this HTML setup

```css
.big-container {
  height: 100vh
}

.small-container {
  overflow: auto;
  height: calc(100vh-300px)
}

.smaller-container {
  overflow: auto
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<body>
  <div class="big-container">
    <div class="small-container">
      <div class="smaller-container">
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <p>paragraph</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Did you miss to add `scrollTo` button?

Comment: Have you tried `.scrollIntoView()`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is perfect solution but i have work my way around with same problem by using following method.

In my case `<main>` tag of document has overflow-auto but when i used `window.scrollTo` then i guess it is refering to main window but overflow is only limited to `<main>` tag so i thought to instruct the element directly

```
const main = document.getElementsByTagName("main");
main[0]["scrollTop"] = 0;
```

i had unique main tag thats why it return single entry with index 0, try to find element by unique identity, after geting that element i set scrollTop to 0 to be able to scroll upto top

In your case try puting class of element in which actual content is children

```
onClick={()=>{const element =
        document.getElementsByClassName("smaller-container");
      element[0]["scrollTop"] = 0;}}
```

:) Please edit if you can make better solution.
Happy Coading!

Answer (score 0):

Its work

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<body>
  <div class="big-container">
    <div class="small-container">
      <div class="smaller-container">
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <p>paragraph</p>
        <p>paragraph</p>
      </div>
       <button onclick="scrollWindow()">
  Scroll
  </button>
    </div>
  </div>
 
</body>

</html>
```

```
.big-container {
  height: 100vh
}

.small-container {
  overflow: auto;
  height: calc(100vh-300px)
}

.smaller-container {
  overflow: auto
}
```

```
function scrollWindow(){
window.scrollTo(0,200)
}
```